# Access helpers from onCreated in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  reactiveVar: new ReactiveVar
});
```

How can I access `reactiveVar` from onCreated to set it up?

```
Template.restaurantEdit.onCreated(function() {
  // Access helpers.reactiveVar from here to set up
  // My goal is to set up data to reactiveVar, ex:
  helpers.reactiveVar = this.data.someData;
});
```

I found there is protected __helpers: `this.view.template.__helpers`

But is there any *Meteor*'s nice way to access helpers? or which is the Meteor's way to set up reactiveVar from loaded `data`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically don't access helpers in Meteor directly. If you want to use [scoped reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) with ReactiveVar, you should do it this way:

```
Template.restaurantEdit.onCreated(function() {
  //define all your reactive variables here
  this.reactiveVar = new ReactiveVar('default value');
});

Template.restaurantEdit.helpers({
  reactiveVar: function() {
    //access reactiveVar template variable from onCreated() hook
    return Template.instance().reactiveVar.get();
  }
});

Template.restaurantEdit.events({
  'click yourselector': function(evt, template) {
    template.reactiveVar.set('new value');
  }
});
```

Read more about scoped reactivity here: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity

Comment: +1 And if you're looking for a reactive way to access the template's data (this was why I was looking for this solution), use `Template.currentData()` (in an autorun of course).

Answer (score 1):

You should set up the reactive variable in your `onCreated()` block and then access it via a `helper`, not vice-versa.

```
Template.restaurantEdit.onCreated(function(){
  this.foo = new ReactiveVar;
});

Template.restaurantEdit.helpers({
  foo: function(){
    return Template.instance().foo.get();
  }
});
```

The helper will update whenever your `ReactiveVar` changes.